# Vuex vs Service for managing state

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

What is the difference (benefits/cons) of using Vuex vs a service for state management.

I am working on an application that displays a catalog of items. These items are fetched from an API. At the moment users have the ability to apply filters and sort the items.

I am using a service to handle updating the view based on what filter the user applies. The items are filtered on the back end so each time a filter is triggered an update method fetches the items from the API.

There's a few levels of component nesting for this application (and these are reused among diff pages with sim functionality) and I used an event bus as a quick way to handle the events and test the API endpoints, but now I need to use Vuex to handle the state.

I am starting to write the Vuex store and I am noticing there's quite a bit of functionality that I'm transferring over from the service.

I would like to know how the too differ?

Comment: what did you create this event bus with? rxjs?

Comment: VueJS, just created another global vue instance to use exclusively for state management but I've since moved from that and have been using a vuex store which seems to be the requirement as the app will grow in features

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively new to VueJS, so please take this with a grain of salt.

I think it depends on the size of the app, as well as the complexity. If you're emitting a lot of events, using state makes sense because you have a single source of truth (a single file, literally) for your app state vs an event bus which will have to be imported into every component. From the Vuex site,

> If you've never built a large-scale SPA and jump right into Vuex, it may feel verbose and daunting. That's perfectly normal - if your app is simple, you will most likely be fine without Vuex. A simple global event bus may be all you need. But if you are building a medium-to-large-scale SPA, chances are you have run into situations that make you think about how to better handle state outside of your Vue components, and Vuex will be the natural next step for you. There's a good quote from Dan Abramov, the author of Redux.

Hope this helps. Good luck :)